# CSS: z-index not working inside a position:relative container

Tags: css

I would like to position the `.wall-panel` `div` behind my `img` (so that the image is visible), but retain all the other positioning in the fiddle. This works without the `position: relative` container, but once inside the container, the `z-index` property seems to do nothing.

What am I doing wrong?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(100vh * 0.4);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  z-index: 1;
}

.wall-panel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='image' src='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/'>
  <div class='wall-panel' />
</div>
<div>
Some other text that positions under the container.
</div>
```

Comment: as a side note, z-index has no effect on the image because its position is static.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`z-index` should be -1 this should work:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(100vh * 0.4);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  z-index: 1;
}

.wall-panel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='image' src='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/'>
  <div class='wall-panel'>
</div>
<div>
Some other text that positions under the container.
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: since the OP accepted this better remove the z-index from the image to make the code coherent .. as actually is a bit wrong since z-index has no meaning there

Answer (score 1):

Make the image positioned because:

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a **positioned**
>   element and its descendants

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index</sup>

And

> A positioned element is an element whose computed position value is
>   either **relative**, **absolute**, **fixed**, or **sticky**. (In other words, it's
>   anything except static.)

<sup>https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position</sup>

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  top: calc(100vh * 0.4);
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.image {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}

.wall-panel {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <img class='image' src='http://lorempixel.com/400/400/'>
  <div class='wall-panel'></div>
</div>
<div>
  Some other text that positions under the container.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply apply position: relative to image as well. It will work.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `z-index` you must add `position: relative` to your block.

See jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/andrewsilent/ber9weqw/